# How to press NSMenuItem programmatically?

Tags: xcode, macos

I want to perform the action which is bound to a NSMenuItem, I'm developing a plugin for osx app. 
Therefore I don't know target method of the menuitem. (target of the menu item returns nil)

How can I press `NSMenuItem` programmatically ?

Comment: I think Automator or AppleScript would work. But that's a lot of code, maybe someone else can come up with something simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the `target` of a menu item is `nil`, that means it targets the responder chain. It's the same as if the menu were connected to the First Responder placeholder in the NIB.

Whether the target is `nil` or a specific object, it is dispatched the same way:

```
[NSApp sendAction:theSelector to:theTarget from:theSender];
```

So, with a menu item, that would be:

```
[NSApp sendAction:menuItem.action to:menuItem.target from:menuItem];
```